# Shape of function output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I have a function which gives me a numpy array with a certain shape, but I don't know yet which shape this array is going to be.

Now I have another function which takes this function as an input. How can I extract now the information about the shape of the numpy array of the first function so I can use it in my second one?

Example:

```
f1 = lambda x: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) # 2x3
def f2(f):
    print(f.shape) # should give me (2,3) here

In: f2(f1)
```

The problem is I want to code it that way so `f1` can have potentially an array with another shape but the code should work for every shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make it so complicated, just call `f` in `f2` and use the array there:

```
f1 = lambda x: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) # 2x3
def f2(f):
    arr = f(1)  # add your inputs here instead of the "1"
    print(arr.shape)

>>> f2(f1)
(2, 3)
```

You could also assign an attribute to your `lambda` function in case you don't want to call it:

```
f1 = lambda x: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) # 2x3
def f2(f):
    print(f.shape)

>>> f1.shape = (2, 3)
>>> f2(f1)
(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably I was thinking to complicated. Can you exand a little bit on the attribute which I can assign to the lambda function? I can't spot a difference in your second code.

Comment: @philmcole I only added the second approach in case you literally wanted the shape to be an attribute of the function `f1`. The important line is where I manually set `f1.shape = (2, 3)`. However, I wouldn't recommend that approach! If the first approach is viable for you that should be the preferred way.